# Is there an rc file for msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, configuration-files, dotfiles

Is there a user config file for msbuild, like a `~/.msbuildrc`?

(Some of the options, like CPU count and verbosity, it seems silly to set per-project -- they're things that vary by user or computer, not by project.)

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`Custom.Before.Microsoft.Common.Tasks` mechanism as described here](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/under-the-hood-of-msbuild-integration.aspx) and [in less depth here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/extending-msbuild/) and [a forum thread here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/21db5834-a048-4d49-bf64-0fa574412b3b)

(There are also [.rsp files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404301.aspx), but those are per-project)